# Bookdown Pandoc Table suppress Numbering

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am working with BookDown for my article. I have three tables. The second table does not contain any caption or label. I am expecting that the third table should take the number 2 but instead it is taking number 3. Is there any way I can suppress number in the second table so that the number of tables continues from the 1st to 3rd table.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems the answer is no. Bookdown uses pandoc with crossref and sending the unnumbered tag does nothing to the table number.

I tried:

```
a   b   c
--- --- ---
1   2   3
4   5   6

: Caption {.unnumbered}
```